# using element <use> with SVG saved in local storage

Tags: javascript, svg, local-storage

I am using`<use>` for svg element "icon" defined on my page

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <use xlink:href="#icon"></use>
</svg>
```

Is there is away to use this(or similar approach) for svg stored in 'localStorage' without create SVG DOM element (no jQuery)?

```
localStorage['mySVG'] = svgData;
```

where "svgData" contains:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 21.969 22.008"><defs>...etc.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an SVG DOM element from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107288/create-an-svg-dom-element-from-a-string)

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107288/create-an-svg-dom-element-from-a-string

Comment: I ment 'directly' without 'innerHTML = svgData;'

Comment: Solved at: https://osvaldas.info/caching-svg-sprite-in-localstorage